# my windowsphone nokia lumia 520 is not downloading any app

Tags: lumia-520

I am not a child but when I try to download any app a message appears on my screen that I should ask my parents to create a family set up I am very upset please help me

Answer (score 0):

Verify the date if birth you have entered when creating the Microsoft Account - you are registered as a minor. Try changing the birthdate (if you are in fact older) or get your parents to set up a family account. Otherwise you'll need to create a new Microsoft account.